# Python: Incrementing class attributes with tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, attributes, increment

Here's a super simple GUI program to help illustrate my question. It has:

- A window:
  `main_window` (`tkinter.Tk()`)
- Two buttons:
  `self.button1` & `self.button2`
- An attribute/variable:
  `self.x` (an integer: `0`)
- A method:
  `xplus1(self)` (adds `1` to `self.x`)

  ---
- `self.button1`:
  Text says `'Quit'`.
  Clicking it will terminate the process, via `tkinter.destroy`.
- `self.button2`:
  Text says `0`, because it's set to `x`.
  Clicking it is supposed to increase `0` by `1`, via `self.xplus1`.

  ---

How can I get the value displayed on `self.button2` to increase when clicked?

```
from tkinter import *  

class Main:  

    def __init__(self):  
        main_window = Tk()

        self.x = 0

        self.button1 = Button(main_window,text=self.x,command=self.xplus1)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = Button(main_window,text='Quit',command=main_window.destroy)
        self.button2.pack()

        mainloop()

    def xplus1(self):
        self.x = self.x + 1

Main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `self.button1.config(text=self.x)` to the definition of `xplus1(self)`:

```
    def xplus1(self):
         self.x = self.x + 1
         self.button1.config(text=self.x)
```